# How do I make a comment system for my website?

Tags: php, html, comments

What would the code be to have a comments section on my website where logged in people can place a comment. I got a database and want to use html and php only. No 3th party involved.
Something simple and not to advanced.

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you. If you have a specific issue, we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: Your best bet is to start with some introductory tutorials for PHP.  A lot of them target this *exact* use case as a demonstration of basic functionality.  We'll be happy to answer any specific questions you have as you develop this, but as it stands right now this is too broad to be meaningfully answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: commenting sction is not a simple matter. I strongly suggest you to show comments authorized by administrators only. Other wise you will receive tons of spam or ugly posts. Moreover, you will need a captcha image to distinguish robots from humans and avoid robots posting. Finally, there are many ways to create such system but its rather complicated to show it here.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out some tutorials:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGmEZY6DBhw

http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/05/comment-system-using-php-and-mysql.html

We are not going to place an entire code here, you should show us that you've tried instead of just asking us to write all of your code.

Comment: This is what I have so far: <form action="comment.php" method="post">
Comments:<br />
<textarea name="comments" id="comments">
Type your message.
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>Well this is what I have so far: